# Get the token access at dispatch with FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I create the login using an instance of `formRequest` as a parameter, once I have validated the user's accesses, I add to the request the parameters that needs the oauth server.

however, I get an error from the server oauth:

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}
```

but when I change the instance of my parameter to Request I don't get this error anymore.

Steps To Reproduce:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use ThrottlesLogins;

    public function store(LoginRequest $loginRequest)
    {
        //$loginRequest->validated();
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($loginRequest)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($loginRequest);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($loginRequest);
        }
        if (Auth::attempt($this->credentials($loginRequest))){
            $client = $this->getClient($loginRequest->name);
            $params = [
                'grant_type'    => 'password',
                'client_id'     => $client->id,
                'client_secret' => $client->secret,
                'username'      => $loginRequest->email,
                'password'      => $loginRequest->password,
                'scopes'         => 'fd',
            ];
            $loginRequest->request->add($params);
            $req = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
            $response = Route::dispatch($req)->getContent();
            return $response;
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($loginRequest);
        $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($loginRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't answer your question, but do you know that you can [create](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#assigning-scopes-to-tokens) a token for a user like this: `$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['scope-1'])->accessToken;`?

Comment: Yes, I know, but can we make a refresh token? (with this method) @DelenaMalan

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded  as a header to your request to 'oauth/token'

```
$req = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');
$req->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$response = Route::dispatch($req)->getContent();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I hijacked the problem by using the `createToken` method of the HasApiTokens trait to generate an access token and be able to continue.